# Benchmarking C++ functions' execution speed with GPIO and oscilloscope

Tags: microcontroller, raspberry-pi, oscilloscope, gpio

For a research project, I'm trying to determine the execution time of various C++ functions on a Raspberry Pi and an STM32 microcontroller.

To do so, I plan on triggering GPIO pulses before and after each function's execution like so:

```
void a() {}
void b() {}
void c() {}

constexpr int REPS = 1000;

int main() {
    // GOAL: get execution times of `a`, `b`, and `c`
    
    // set GPIO signal
    for (int i = 0; i < REPS; ++i) {
        a();
    }
    // clear GPIO signal

    // set GPIO signal
    for (int i = 0; i < REPS; ++i) {
        b();
    }
    // clear GPIO signal

    // set GPIO signal
    for (int i = 0; i < REPS; ++i) {
        c();
    }
    // clear GPIO signal
    
    return 0;
}
```

However, I'm not really sure how to do this hardware-wise. I've used an oscilloscope before, but only for basic features, and I don't know how to use the triggering feature that well.

I have the Rigol DS1000E oscilloscope if that matters. Any ideas for a workflow would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really sure what you expect here, do you need a "Press the key named _trig_ on your oscilloscope"? I mean, everything on how to trigger a signal is in the manual.

Comment: wouldn't a software solution be more sensible? Take the hardware delay and measurement uncertainties out of the loop. Plus, it's easy to just count cycles, assuming you don't change clock speeds in your functions under test.

Comment: even if you really want to do the measurement in hardware: instead of toggling a GPIO line, you could just as easily enable a hardware timer/counter, and stop it after execution. That would take the same amount of overhead. And, you can then just read the timer value. But again, your ARM cores allow you to know how long execution took. No special tricks required.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I personally am in favour of a software approach, however my research advisor advised me to use an oscilloscope as it is apparently more precise than microcontroller software timers.

Comment: @RichardRobinson say hello to your advisor from me and ask them to discuss this with you in detail. If you want to determine the speed of software, you better do it relative to the oscillator that the CPU is running on – or else, you'd simply incorporate the random variations of your CPU clock speed relative to the oscilloscope frequency / time standard. On the other hand, if you need "real-world" performance guarantees of e.g. a motor controller, he's right, you need to measure against some "real-world" clock. But then you should use a reliable external oscillator,

Comment: which you should adjust to the slowest the oscillator in the final product would ever be likely to run; otherwise, you're just measuring a random operating point. (note that the built-in RC oscillators of microcontrollers are often +- 4% in speed variation; the crystal oscillators that you find in most electronics are +- 25 to 100 ppm, your scope will probably have something like a +-10 ppm clock; the instantaneous frequencies vary from individual device to device, over time and temperature)

Comment: (your advisor isn't *wrong*, per se, by the way: there's plenty of ways to mess up software timing measurements, and if you're used to working with scopes and such, it's easy to operate them right – but you're not used to scopes and such, and your problem seems to be a software problem, so the software solution is the preferable solution, imho.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this in software, and you should. That would eradicate all need for measurement equipment, interaction with hardware, all analog uncertainties, and reduces opportunity for mistakes.

Your ARM cores have [Cycle Count registers](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0439c/BABJFFGJ.html). You can just enable the cycle counting, and get the values, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37345912/4433386) on your STM32 (assuming that's a Cortex-M3 or M4).

The Raspberry Pi is not a single device, so it's even harder to advice here. But, all of them run an ARM A-something application processor, with normal debug/tracing facilities built in. It shouldn't be hard, especially if you have a sensible runtime on that.

If you're using one of the *really* small Cortex-M0 microcontrollers, maybe the cycle counter facilities aren't there (I don't know). If that's the case, you could always  just as easily as toggling GPIO enable a hardware timer/counter, and stop it after execution. That would take the same amount of overhead. And, you can then just read the timer value.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you'll have to read the manual for the scope and learn how triggering works.

Besides that, use the "Measure" feature to have it display the width of the pulse:

[image]

First, use this code:

```
// set GPIO signal
// clear GPIO signal
```

Measure pulse width, this will give you a baseline. Then, use this code:

```
// set GPIO signal
a();
// clear GPIO signal
```

Measure pulse width again, substract the previously measured baseline, and you get a timing for function a().

Comment: Yes, this is the advantage of a scope, you don't need loops for an accurate measurement.

Comment: @Mattman944 it depends on what you want to test, though. If this is a function that, indeed, will run in a tight loop on a microcontroller with caches, then looping is the right thing to do

Comment: @peufeu would it be possible to measure all of `a, b` and `c` in one go instead of individually? In practice, there will probably be dozens of functions so I would like to automate the process as much as possible, thanks!

Comment: Then it would be more practical to use the cycle count register.